# Cannot resolve/find OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to follow some tutorials to learn how to secure a very simply spring-boot REST app with oauth2. I am trying to implement the Java config file as done on https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/10/08/secure-rest-services-with-spring-security/. 
That starts with

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String applicationName = ServiceConfiguration.CRM_NAME;
```

However, when I add that to my project, my IDE tells me it cannot resolve OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter or ServiceConfiguration, and I cannot find a import (or a maven dependency with a import) that resolves.

In my pom.xml, I have

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have also tried to add this import to the class:
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.*;

Even with that and making sure to reimport the dependencies, I am still being told that that cannot be resolved.

Any ideas as to what I am missing? Is there a maven dependency I need? Do I need to have this spring config class in a certain place in my project and/or have something specific in a xml config file or something...?

Thanks for any help. Let me know if there is more detail I need to provide

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when the code you're referring to was written, the Java configuration for OAuth2 was a work in progress and has since changed.

[This article](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/18/spring-security-oauth-2-0-0-rc1-available) might be a better starting point. The [OAuth2 samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java) are also now using Java Config, so are a good resource to based your code on.